# Generating graphs with top label different from down

Tags: pgfplots

%how use the top label diferrent form the down label?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{siunitx} % SI-units
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{units} % to add units easily to axis
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween} % to fill inbetween curves
\usepgfplotslibrary{colormaps} % to create colormaps
\pgfplotsset{width=22cm, height=9cm}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest} %(making it only compatalbe with
%new releases of pgfplots)
\usepackage{tikz}
\pgfdeclarehorizontalshading{visiblelight}{50bp}{
color(0.00000000000000bp)=(violet);
color(8.33333333333333bp)=(blue);
color(16.66666666666670bp)=(cyan);
color(25.00000000000000bp)=(green);
color(33.33333333333330bp)=(yellow);
color(41.66666666666670bp)=(orange);
color(50.00000000000000bp)=(red)
}%

\begin{document}
\addtolength{\textwidth}{4cm}
\addtolength{\textheight}{6cm}

\addtolength{\hoffset}{-4.5cm}
\addtolength{\voffset}{-1cm} 
\begin{tikzpicture}
%\pgfplotsset{width=18 cm}
\begin{axis}[
xlabel={Comprimento de onda},
xticklabel style = {font=\small,yshift=0.2ex},
xmin=10^-13,
xmax=10^3,
x unit=\si{\meter},
xmode=log,
ymin=0,
ymax=1,
height=3cm,
yticklabels={},
ytick=\empty,
legend cell align=left,
legend style={at={(0.85,-0.77)},anchor=north}
]
\addplot[draw=none, name path=start, forget plot] coordinates{(10^-12,0)(10^-12,1)};
\addplot[draw=none, name path=gamma, forget plot] coordinates{(10^-9,0)(10^-9,1)};
\addplot[draw=none, name path=xrays, forget plot] coordinates{(10^-2,0)(10^-2,1)};
\addplot[draw=none, name path=uv, forget plot] coordinates{(4*10^-7,0)(4*10^-7,1)};
\addplot[draw=none, name path=visible, forget plot] coordinates{(7.5*10^-7,0)(7.5*10^-7,1)};
\addplot[draw=none, name path=ir, forget plot] coordinates{(10^2.5,0)(10^2.5,1)};
\addplot[draw=none, name path=microwave, forget plot] coordinates{(10^5,0)(10^5,1)};
\addplot[draw=none, name path=radiowave, forget plot] coordinates{(10^9,0)(10^9,1)};

\node[fill=none] 
    at (10^-12,0.7) {
    \begin{footnotesize}
    $raios$
    \end{footnotesize}};
\node[fill=none] 
    at (*10^-12,0.4) {\begin{small}
    $gama$
    \end{small}};

\node[fill=none] 
    at (2*10^-10,0.55) {\begin{footnotesize} $\text{raios x}$ \end{footnotesize}};

\node[fill=none] 
    at (0.3*10^-7,0.55) {\begin{footnotesize} $ultravioleta$ \end{footnotesize}};

\addplot[shading=visiblelight, area legend] fill between[of=uv and visible];

\node[fill=none] 
    at (10^-5,0.55) {\begin{footnotesize} $infravermelho$ \end{footnotesize}};

\node[fill=none] 
    at (10^-2,0.55) {\begin{footnotesize} $\text{micro-ondas}$ \end{footnotesize}};

\node[fill=none] 
    at (10^2,0.55) {\begin{footnotesize} $\text{radio}$ \end{footnotesize}};

\end{axis}

\begin{axis}[
    axis x line=top,
    xticklabel = {},
    xmin=10^-24,
    xmax=10^-2,
    xmode=log,
    ymin=0,
    ymax=1,
    height=3cm,
    yticklabels={},
    ytick=\empty,
    x unit=\si{Hz},
%  x axis style=red!75!black
]
\end{axis}



\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

[image: the top label are not right]

Comment: (1) welcome, (2) please explain in words what your problem is. It is currently not particularly obvious from the MWE alone.

Comment: Thanks. I am new here and not understan so well how the site works. 
I am trying make a graph where in the xlabel botom there is scale and in the top xlabel there is another scale. Like in a ordinary eltromagnetic spectrum.

Comment: Please update your question with this information. Also people here might not be familiar with an ordinary electromagnetic spectrum. Might be an idea to post also an image of what you have now and perhaps an example what what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your attempt you were on the right track and you almost had it. You need to add `xtick pos` with the right values to each of the `axis` environments and then you are there. For details (and some more improvements) have a look at the comments in the code.

```
% used PGFPlots v1.16
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \usepgfplotslibrary{
        fillbetween,
        units,
    }
    \pgfplotsset{
        % use this `compat' level or higher
        compat=1.11,
        %
        % moved common axis options here
        my axis style/.style={
            width=22cm,
            height=3cm,
            ymin=0,
            ymax=1,
            xticklabel style={
                font=\small,
            },
            ytick=\empty,
            axis on top,
        },
    }
    \pgfdeclarehorizontalshading{visiblelight}{50bp}{
        color(0.00000000000000bp)=(violet);
        color(8.33333333333333bp)=(blue);
        color(16.66666666666670bp)=(cyan);
        color(25.00000000000000bp)=(green);
        color(33.33333333333330bp)=(yellow);
        color(41.66666666666670bp)=(orange);
        color(50.00000000000000bp)=(red)
    }
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    % because `xmode=log' does not work in styles I changed `axis' to `semilogxaxis'
    \begin{semilogxaxis}[
        my axis style,
        %
        xlabel={Comprimento de onda},
        xmin=1e-13,
        xmax=1e3,
        x unit=\si{\meter},
        ytick=\empty,
        xtick pos=lower,    % <-- this plots ticks on the lower border only
    ]
        \addplot [draw=none,name path=start]     coordinates {(1e-12,0)(1e-12,1)};
        \addplot [draw=none,name path=gamma]     coordinates {(1e-9,0)(1e-9,1)};
        \addplot [draw=none,name path=xrays]     coordinates {(1e-2,0)(1e-2,1)};
        \addplot [draw=none,name path=uv]        coordinates {(4e-7,0)(4e-7,1)};
        \addplot [draw=none,name path=visible]   coordinates {(7.5e-7,0)(7.5e-7,1)};
        \addplot [draw=none,name path=ir]        coordinates {(10^2.5,0)(10^2.5,1)};
        \addplot [draw=none,name path=microwave] coordinates {(1e5,0)(10^5,1)};
        \addplot [draw=none,name path=radiowave] coordinates {(1e9,0)(1e9,1)};

        \addplot [
            shading=visiblelight,
            area legend,
        ] fill between [
            of=uv and visible,
        ];

        % added scope to simplify node options
        \begin{scope}[
            font=\footnotesize,
        ]
            % (use `\textit' instead of math mode)
            \node               at (1e-12,0.7)   {\textit{raios}};
            \node [font=\small] at (1e-12,0.4)   {\textit{gama}};
            \node               at (2e-10,0.55)  {raios x};
            \node               at (0.3e-7,0.55) {\textit{ultravioleta}};

            \node               at (1e-5,0.55)   {\textit{infravermelho}};
            \node               at (1e-2,0.55)   {micro-ondas};
            \node               at (1e2,0.55)    {radio};
        \end{scope}

    \end{semilogxaxis}

    \begin{semilogxaxis}[
        my axis style,
        %
        axis x line*=top,   % <-- (use starred form to avoid arrow on axis line)
        xmin=1e-24,
        xmax=1e-2,
        x unit=\si{Hz},
        xtick pos=upper,    % <-- this plots ticks on the upper border only
    ]
    \end{semilogxaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]